# Why access the props of calling element is not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This, React Native-code, is throwing an error /when button is pressed:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

const handleClick = (event, {title}) => {
  console.log('name of button was ', title);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View><Button title='Test' onPress={handleClick} /></View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

While this, React-code, isn't:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const handleClick = (event, {title}) => {
  console.log('name of button was ', title);
}

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">    
      <Button title='Test' onClick={handleClick} >Test</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error in the first one is: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.title')"

Why is that, what is the difference between React and React-Native in such a situation?
And to get similar result in React Native, how should I write the same code? That is, how to get the properties of calling element?

The React Native version has been build made with react-native cli version, pure project with no add-ons.
The React version has been made with Create React App and added with Semantic Ui, but no further add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the props of the calling element, unless that element decides to pass them to the callback. In your case, it's a feature of semantic-ui-react's [Button](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/) component - see the documentation of its `onClick` prop.

So you need to replace replace the code in your react-native example with something like this to explicitly pass the title:

```
onClick={e => handleClick(e, {title: 'Test'})}
```

or simplify it as `onClick={e => handleClick(e, 'Test')}` and remove the object unpacking in `handleClick` if all you need is the title.